# How to select a range of observations using R

Tags: r, select, range

I need to select a range of observations from variable `"position"` and keep getting errors.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
newfile <- myfile[which(myfile$position (18300000:18400000), ]
```

and this error comes up:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "newfile <- myfile[which(myfile$position 18300000"
```

Comment: please give more information on what you want to do and on the variable `position`. Is it logical, do you want to simply select the rows 183.. to 184... from the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, you have to specify that you want the varaible `%in%` the range:

```
newfile <- myfile[myfile$position %in% (18300000:18400000), ]
```

Note that you don't need to use `which` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try

```
newfile <- myfile [myfile$position] [18300000:18400000, ]
```

if its the vertical position